# Number of ordered pairs with given lcm

Tags: number-theory

Suppose $(p,q)$ is an ordered pair of  natural numbers with lcm $r^2.s^4.t^2$, where $r,s,t$ are distinct primes.We have to find the number of all such ordered pairs.
One simple idea I tried is to fix p and then take all possible values of q s.t. the lcm is preserved.But my calculations get cumbersome.Would somebody please help me?Thank u.

Answer (score 1):

Either $p$ or $q$ must have a factor of $r^2$. The other one can have either $r^0, r^1$ or $r^2$. That's five ways to the distribute $r$-factors. Similarily, the $s$-factors may be distributed in $9$ ways, and the $t$ factors can be distributed in $5$ ways. All in all we get $5.9.5 = 225$ different pairs.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Arthur for the elegant solution.

Comment: I think the answer should be 172

Comment: @MayankDeora How do you figure?

Comment: @Arthur how did you distribute r-factors in 5 ways? Let me see whether i am correct or not then i would tell you my way.

Comment: @MayankDeora Letting $(a, b)$ mean $p$ has $a$ factors of $r$ and $q$ has $b$ factors of $r$, we have $$(0,2)\,\, (1,2)\,\, (2,2)\,\,(2,1)\,\,(2,0)$$